# Android encrypt/decrypt sqlite database 100% secure

Tags: java, android, sqlite, security, encryption

I am a new born baby in android security point of view. What I am trying to do is encrypt/decrypt Sqlite Database.

I have gone through multiple tutorial but nothing seems to work.I have gone through Sql Cipher link but here I code and I am getting issue given below:

```
Type Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lnet/sqlcipher/AbstractCursor$SelfContentObserver;
```

Also I don't need password protected file. I have use Cipher default class that Android library provide like below:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
```

But I doesn't find it secure. I suppose it can be decrypt by hackers. I need proper 100% encryption and decryption security of Sqlite Database.

Comment: "But I do[...]n't find it secure" -- Why do you think it's not secure? If used correctly, it should be quite secure - if `privateKey` is *not* stored anywhere on the device.

Comment: It is necessary to store data locally

Comment: "I have gone through Sql Cipher link but here I code I am getting below issue" -- we cannot help you without more to go on, such as your `build.gradle` files (if you are using Android Studio). "Also I don't need password protected file" -- hard-coding a password will be insecure, as will be generating a password and keeping it on internal storage. It is theoretically possible, using a hardware-backed `KeyStore` on fairly new Android devices, to avoid a password *and* avoid a hard-coded password, though I have not tried this yet and relatively few devices support it today.

Comment: You probably won't have to encrypt the whole database (file). Maybe you can just encrypt those values which really are sensitive.

Comment: @HannoBinder Actually my whole Database is sensitive.So I need full database encryption.Please let me know your suggestion how to implement and what will be the better approach.

Comment: `100% secure` **Nothing** can ever be `100% secure`, in computer science. A motivated hacker will always be able break your security.

Comment: thnk you all for your responses :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Lite is a lightweight database system.Having said that it also has few hacks possible into the system to make it encrypted OR password protected. Here are few of them which I know :-

1. [SEE](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html):

> The SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) is an add-on to the public domain version of SQLite that allows an application to read and write encrypted database files. Four different encryption algorithms are supported:
>
> RC4
>
> AES-128 in OFB mode
>
> AES-128 in CCM mode
>
> AES-256 in OFB mode

2. [WxSQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsqlite/):

> A wxWidgets style c++ wrapper that also implements SQLite's encryption.

3.[SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/)

> SQLCipher has a small footprint and great performance so it’s ideal for protecting embedded application databases and is well suited for mobile development.

Personally I recommend as per your needs SQLCipher is the best one to go for.I have tried it.Its highly recommended **Open-Source** System.

Comment: Yes I feel so SQLCipher will be good.I have also resolve the Multiple dex files issue.now will check where I will go now :).Sry I unable to vote bcz I have less reputation :(